# rootfs building tools

Tags: compiling

I need to build some Ubuntu-based rootfs. This rootfs consist of some packages from ubuntu repo with custom configs and some packages from our own private repo.

Right now in our team it is done by running bunch of shell/python scripts in chroot after debootstrap.

Is there any more reliable and suitable instruments to build rootfs?